# SVG manipulation with d3 joins and text positioning

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've been trying to make a diagram with d3 and I've just about got a chart representing what I'm after, which is some relatively scaled doughnut charts.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qxhzd/1/

And my code:

```
function jsonToPieSlices(jsonScores) {
data = [];
var total_scores = 0;
for (var i in jsonScores){
   total_scores += parseInt(jsonScores[i].score, 10);
}
var factor = 100/total_scores;
var previous_angle = 0;

for (var i in jsonScores) {
  current_angle = ((jsonScores[i].score*factor)+previous_angle);
  data.push([previous_angle, current_angle, jsonScores[i].color]);
  previous_angle = current_angle;
}
return data;
}

function multi_nut() {

 var jsonScores = [{'topic': 'Credit Card Processing', 'total_scores': 35, 'scale': 1, 'position': '150,200', 'scores':[
                    {"color": '#522275', "name": 'site1.com', "score": 7},
                    {"color": '#5C6BD6', "name": 'site2.com', "score": 18},
                    {"color": '#FF7D33', "name": 'site3.com', "score": 3},
                    {"color": '#FFC433', "name": 'site4.com', "score": 2},
                    {"color": '#41B224', "name": 'site5.com', "score": 2},
                    {"color": '#36835D', "name": 'site6.com', "score": 3}]},

                    {'topic': 'Credit Card Reader', 'total_scores': 38, 'scale': 0.409090909, 'position': '650,250', 'scores':[
                    {"color": '#522275', "name": 'site1.com', "score": 7},
                    {"color": '#5C6BD6', "name": 'site2.com', "score": 8},
                    {"color": '#FF7D33', "name": 'site3.com', "score": 8},
                    {"color": '#FFC433', "name": 'site4.com', "score": 5},
                    {"color": '#41B224', "name": 'site5.com', "score": 7},
                    {"color": '#36835D', "name": 'site6.com', "score": 3}]},

                    {'topic': 'Mobile Payments', 'total_scores': 10, 'scale': 0.318181818, 'position': '900,560', 'scores':[
                    {"color": '#522275', "name": 'site1.com', "score": 4},
                    {"color": '#5C6BD6', "name": 'site2.com', "score": 3},
                    {"color": '#FF7D33', "name": 'site3.com', "score": 1},
                    {"color": '#FFC433', "name": 'site4.com', "score": 0 },
                    {"color": '#41B224', "name": 'site5.com', "score": 0},
                    {"color": '#36835D', "name": 'site6.com', "score": 2}]},

                    {'topic': 'Android Readers', 'total_scores': 9, 'scale': 0.136363636, 'position': '1950,1700', 'scores':[
                    {"color": '#522275', "name": 'site1.com', "score": 3},
                    {"color": '#5C6BD6', "name": 'site2.com', "score": 0},
                    {"color": '#FF7D33', "name": 'site3.com', "score": 3},
                    {"color": '#FFC433', "name": 'site4.com', "score": 0},
                    {"color": '#41B224', "name": 'site5.com', "score": 3},
                    {"color": '#36835D', "name": 'site6.com', "score": 0}]},

                    {'topic': 'Iphone Readers', 'total_scores': 22, 'scale': 0.318181818, 'position': '950,850', 'scores':[
                    {"color": '#522275', "name": 'site1.com', "score": 7},
                    {"color": '#5C6BD6', "name": 'site2.com', "score": 3},
                    {"color": '#FF7D33', "name": 'site3.com', "score": 5},
                    {"color": '#FFC433', "name": 'site4.com', "score": 0},
                    {"color": '#41B224', "name": 'site5.com', "score": 7},
                    {"color": '#36835D', "name": 'site6.com', "score": 0}]},
];




var cScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
var vis = d3.select("#svg_donut");

for (var i in jsonScores) {
data = jsonToPieSlices(jsonScores[i].scores);

var translation = "scale("+jsonScores[i].scale+") translate("+jsonScores[i].position+")"
// if (i==2) alert(translation);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(50)
.outerRadius(100)
.startAngle(function(d){return cScale(d[0]);})
.endAngle(function(d){return cScale(d[1]);});


vis.append('g')
.attr('id', "group-"+i)
.attr('class', "node")
.selectAll("path")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("d", arc)
.style("fill", function(d){return d[2];})


.attr("transform", translation)
 .transition().delay(function(d, i) { return i * 500; }).duration(500)
  .attrTween('d', function(d) {
       var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle+0.1, d.endAngle);
       return function(t) {
           d.endAngle = i(t);
         return arc(d);
       }
  })

}



multi_nut();
```

My question is 2 fold:
As a quick fix I need to get the number of the chart (currently i+1) into the center of each chart. All my attempts result in the text being positioned relative to the document, not the group that contains each chart.

In the bigger picture I'm pretty sure I should be able to make this work using the data (possibly requires reformatting) without the horrible loop I've put in, and also without the explicit positioning I have added - by using some kind of bubble layout.

Any assistance would be gratefully received!

Comment: Are you adding text as an SVG `<text>` element or as HTML content?  Because you can transform `<text>` positions the same as any other SVG element.  But your code would be simpler if you applied the transforms to the `<g>` elements instead of to each arc-path individually.  Then you'd just have to add the text to the group, set it's CSS to centre it, and it would be right where you want it.

Comment: On how to re-write your code to take better advantage of D3, look at this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111

Comment: Or, here's a more step-by-step tutorial: http://schoolofdata.org/2013/10/01/pie-and-donut-charts-in-d3-js/

Comment: I'm adding it as text, but can't seem to get it into the appropriate group AmeliaBR, could you suggest how I could do this with my current code? Thanks for the links, the second one is how I got this far - this is day one of d3 for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your `<g>` grouping elements in a variable so you can access them later to add the text.

```
var g = vis.append('g')
  .attr('id', "group-"+i)
  .attr('class', "node")
  .attr("transform", translation);  
  //translate the entire group, not individual paths

g.selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d){return d[2];})

g.append("text")  //add a single text element to each group
  .text(i+1);
```

But again, look at the multiple-pie chart example, and read [this tutorial on nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) to figure out how to draw all your pie charts at once without a `for` loop.  Your text element will automatically inherit the data from its parent group, so you can use `.text(function(d,i) {return i+1;})` to access the chart index if you do it with nested selections.

Comment: Thanks for that example AmeliaBR, I SWEAR I tried that but was getting an undefined method, no doubt some stupid mistake on my behalf! I will get back to the nested selections in the morning and re-read that information while I'm not as tired.